Does mathematics have a solution to this problem - matrix to match predefined thresholds
I work with risk matrices that are the product of a severity and a likelihood vectors. For example 5 likelihood values from 1 - 5, and 5 severity values from 1 - 5, which yield a 5x5 matrix with values from 1 to 25. Clients then define threshold values to saying that, e.g. values over 15 are considered "high risk".
Sometimes the clients already have an existing matrix they use where the 25 fields (the exact dimensions are irrelevant) are already classified in some way they see it fit, but without any numbers. Then I would have to come up with the actual numbers and thresholds that produce the same results. Example:

Don't mind the numbers 1-5 on the axis, they are meaningless in this context. The job is to come up with 5 severity and 5 likelihood values that give a matrix when multiplied, and make up corresponding threshold values that match the requirements. This is sometimes trivial, sometimes requires some trial-and-error. In this case a valid solution would be: [2, 3, 4, 5, 7] and [2, 3, 4, 6, 9] with VH more than 27, H more than 17, L below 10:

The problem with this is obviously that depending on the complexity, by purely staring at it there is no guarantee that I can come up with a solution. After looking at it for hours I might not even be able to tell if there is a solution at all. Not to mention that this process is a disgrace to science. This MUST have a solution in the realm of mathematics, this is what I would like to learn.
As far as my math knowledge goes, this is a matrix, where certain (a large number of) inequations can be defined, for example AB[1,2] > AB[1,1] and so on. We also know that the 2 vectors, A and B will contain increasing numbers, so for example [1, 3, 2, 4, 5] is probably not going to make a good solution (although it might in some cases).
I also find it very disturbing that this has an infinite number of solutions, but ideally I'm looking for the "best" solution, that is: preferably uses small numbers, and only positive integers.
I can't really imagine how mathematics would solve this problem, but I would very much like to know the process.

I am having some trouble understanding your question; please let me know if I have interpreted this correctly. You are given a $5 \times 5$ matrix whose entries are $4$ classifications (for your example L, M, H, VH) and you are given $3$ client-defined thresholds corresponding to each classification (for instance, $15$ might be given as the boundary between M and H). Your goal is to come up with $10$ numbers ($5$ for each row and $5$ for each column) such that each value in the matrix falls into the range corresponding to the classification of that entry. Is that correct?

It might help to make some restrictions on this problem. For example, can we guarantee that the degree of risk increases as we go to the right? For instance, can we guarantee that there is no row that has entries L, M, H, M, L?

It might be useful for you to know that a matrix whose entries correspond to a multiplication table is called a rank-1 matrix.

@BenGrossmann, I'm given this first image. I make up the thresholds while working out the severity / likelihood values. My goal is to find out if the given classification is possible at all using our multiplication method, and if yes, exactly what severity / likelihood values i have to configure, and what are the corresponding threshold values.
Your second comment: I think it is reasonable to assume that the values increase from one corner to the opposite corner.

I'm not sure about the general answer, but my intuition is that your mutliplication-based rating will always produce "linear" boundaries between classifications. For instance, I think it is impossible to produce a suitable table for the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
H & H & H & H & VH\
M & M & M & H & H\
M & M & M & M & H\
L & L & M & M & H\
L & L & M & M & H
}
$$
because the boundary between the "H-region" and "M_region" does not follow any line.

@BenGrossmann I was thinking that with sufficiently large 5th values it would be possible, and behold:
[2, 3, 4, 5, 12] and [4, 5, 8, 9, 23] yield:
$\begin{pmatrix}48 & 60 & 96 & 108 & 276\\ 20 & 25 & 40 & 45 & 115\\ 16 & 20 & 32 & 36 & 92\\ 12 & 15 & 24 & 27 & 69\\ 8 & 10 & 16 & 18 & 46\end{pmatrix}$
VH: >150, H: >45, L: < 16 I have written a script that brute forces the problem, but it can take a while to run it... Mathematics would be nicer.

Interesting. I'll have to thing about it

I suppose it's worth noting that there is no inherent difference between using multiplication and using addition; setting thresholds for $v_i \cdot w_j$ is equivalent to setting thresholds for $\log(v_i) + \log(w_j)$.
